# Getting top distinct records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is probably something very simple, so forgive my blonde moment :)

I have a table 'album'

```
* albumId
* albumOwnerId (who created)
* albumCSD (create stamp date)
```

Now what I am trying to do is to select the top 10 most recently updated albums. But, I don't want 10 albums from the same person coming back - I only want one album per unique person. I.E 10 albums from 10 different people.

So, this is what I have below, but it is not working properly and I just can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT(albumOwnerId), albumId
FROM album
ORDER BY albumCSD DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Here is some example data, followed by what I am trying to get. Hope this makes it clearer.

DATA:

```
albumOwnerID, albumId, albumCSD
18, 194, '2010-10-23 11:02:30'
23, 193, '2010-10-22 11:39:59'
22, 192, '2010-10-12 21:48:16'
21, 181, '2010-10-12 20:34:11'
21, 178, '2010-10-12 20:20:16'
19, 168, '2010-10-12 18:31:55'
18, 167, '2010-10-11 21:06:55'
20, 166, '2010-10-11 21:01:47'
18, 165, '2010-10-11 21:00:32'
20, 164, '2010-10-11 20:50:06'
17, 145, '2010-10-10 18:54:24'
17, 144, '2010-10-10 18:49:28'
17, 143, '2010-10-10 18:48:08'
17, 142, '2010-10-10 18:46:54'
16, 130, '2010-10-10 16:17:57'
16, 129, '2010-10-10 16:17:26'
16, 128, '2010-10-10 16:07:21'
15, 119, '2010-10-10 15:24:28'
15, 118, '2010-10-10 15:24:11'
14, 100, '2010-10-09 18:22:49'
14, 99, '2010-10-09 18:18:46'
11, 98, '2010-10-09 15:50:13'
11, 97, '2010-10-09 15:44:09'
11, 96, '2010-10-09 15:42:28'
11, 95, '2010-10-09 15:37:25'
```

DESIRED DATA:

```
18, 194, '2010-10-23 11:02:30'
23, 193, '2010-10-22 11:39:59'
22, 192, '2010-10-12 21:48:16'
21, 181, '2010-10-12 20:34:11'
19, 168, '2010-10-12 18:31:55'
17, 145, '2010-10-10 18:54:24'
16, 130, '2010-10-10 16:17:57'
15, 119, '2010-10-10 15:24:28'
14, 100, '2010-10-09 18:22:49'
11, 98, '2010-10-09 15:50:13'
```

Comment: it's so long by me, but ... have you experimented with groupby albumownerid?!

Comment: you forgot albumownerid 20, didn't you?!

Comment: @Mur. Correct - well spotted. I edited the desired result by hand and must have skipped 20 by accident!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get results, you want to have, with this query

```
SELECT albumOwnerID, albumId, albumCSD
FROM album
WHERE albumCSD in
(SELECT  Max(album.albumCSD) AS MaxvonalbumCSD
FROM album
GROUP BY album.albumOwnerID);
```

However in MS Access

Comment: Hi Mur - Thanks - that works just fine in MySql and provided the required result! Just need to be ordered DESC, but that's nothing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
select albumOwnerID, albumID
from album
Group by albumOwnerID, albumID
Order by albumcsd desc
LIMIT 0,10
```

EDIT:

```
select albumOwnerID, albumID 
from album
where albumOwnerID in (select distinct albumOwnerID from album order by albumCSD )
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Hi Sachin. That did not work. It yields exactly the same result with or without the group by clause. AlbumOwnerId is not distinct.

Comment: @Cheeky - Can albumID be different for same ownerID? If yes, then please use `Group by albumOwnerID` and remove albumID from group by

Comment: That is what I tried originally but is incorrect, as the albumOwnerIds come back in the wrong order.

Comment: and if you try to select albumOwnerID, albumID from (select albumOwnerId, albumId FROM album 
ORDER BY albumCSD DESC) Group by albumOwnerID LIMIT 0,10

Comment: Hi Mur - that query does not even execute. Error -  "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Hi Sachin - thanks, but that did not work at all. Results were far off. Maybe I will post some example data at the top to illustrate more clearly what I'm expecting.

Comment: @Cheeky - Sorry for trouble, but I do not have mysql installed. Hence I could only give you query ideas. I guess Mur's query is nearest. You can resolve the error you are getting by adding some alias after select subquery like `(select .... ) x` where x is alias.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway Sachin.